# Javascript canvas animation not working properly when canvas is heighr than screen size

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, height, responsive

I have a javascript canvas animation that I am using as a section "background". I have set the canvas width and height to the same as the sections height and width with javascript and it works. There is another div inside of a section (besides canvas) and I have set the sections height to never be smaller than this div's contents height and that also works. I have used debouncing and the resize function and that also works fine but I have a problem with animation when the canvas height is bigger than screen size. Here is the URL to the page where this is happening as I can't explain in words what is happening to the animation:

https://tjaseda.github.io/Portfolio/

The problem is best seen when the window is resized as the landscape mode (height > width). As you can see the canvas gets resized properly and the content never overflows it but can you explain what is the reason for animation to acts like this?

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<section id ="header" class="top">
      <canvas id="myCanvas">
      </canvas>
      <div class="vertical-center hero-text text-center">  
         <div class="container">
         </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.top {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #4169E1, #00BFFF);
}

.vertical-center {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 10%;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(func, 0);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var header = document.getElementById('header');

    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = header.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = header.offsetHeight;

var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    canvas.width = header.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = header.offsetHeight;

    var innerWidth = canvas.width;
    var innerHeight = canvas.height;

}, 50);

window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

*This JS code is for debouncing and resizing. I have a requestAnimationFrame(animate); inside of function(animate)*

Any help will be very much appreciated.